Power Query - Dynamic date filter from beginning of the year till today
I have a column with dates and I would like to dynamically show only the data dating from the beginning of the current year till today. So both the year and the "today" must be dynamic. Hence every time the query is refreshed the results will change.
I have tried adding a filter to show this year first, but then I can't figure out the "till today" part. Other discussions say to select a random date and then change the date part with "currentday" but that didn't work either.
Kindly note that I am a beginner, intermediate at best, so please excuse my explanation.

You can grab today date with Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
Use that to create a filter on the date column, like below, which I crafted in home ... advanced editor...
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dates", type date}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each 
    Date.Year([Dates]) >=  Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) and // in this calendar year
    Number.From([Dates]) <= Number.From(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())) // up until today
)
in #"Filtered Rows"


